# UICollectionViewCell Constraint Issues

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Look hear for edits

[image]So I have a comments feature in my app that users use to communicate. Each comment has a pic, some text and button that lets you either flag or reply to comments. As seen in the picture below[image]

However as seen in the picture there is a clear problem. If you add too much text it seems to run right over the button. Is there anyway I can prevent this from happening I think it looks really bad.

Below is my sorce code for reference I'm thinking it might be my constraints but I am not entirely sure.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import Firebase

protocol CommentCellDelegate: class {
    func optionsButtonTapped(cell: CommentCell)
    func handleProfileTransition(tapGesture: UITapGestureRecognizer)
}
class CommentCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    weak var delegate: CommentCellDelegate? = nil
    override var reuseIdentifier : String {
        get {
            return "cellID"
        }
        set {
            // nothing, because only red is allowed
        }
    }
    var didTapOptionsButtonForCell: ((CommentCell) -> Void)?

    var comment: CommentGrabbed?{
        didSet{
            guard let comment = comment else{
                return
            }
          //  print("apples")
            // textLabel.text = comment.content
            //shawn was also here
            profileImageView.loadImage(urlString: comment.user.profilePic!)
            //  print(comment.user.username)
            let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: comment.user.username!, attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)])

            attributedText.append(NSAttributedString(string: " " + (comment.content), attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)]))
            textView.attributedText = attributedText


        }
    }

    let textView: UITextView = {
        let textView = UITextView()
        textView.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)
        textView.isScrollEnabled = false
        textView.isEditable = false
        return textView
    }()


    lazy var profileImageView: CustomImageView = {
        let iv = CustomImageView()
        iv.clipsToBounds = true
        iv.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        iv.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleProfileTransition)))
        iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        return iv
    }()

    lazy var flagButton: UIButton = {
        let flagButton = UIButton(type: .system)
        flagButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "icons8-Info-64"), for: .normal)
        flagButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(optionsButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
        return flagButton
    }()

    @objc func optionsButtonTapped (){
        didTapOptionsButtonForCell?(self)
    }

    @objc func onOptionsTapped() {
        delegate?.optionsButtonTapped(cell: self)
    }
    @objc func handleProfileTransition(tapGesture: UITapGestureRecognizer){
        delegate?.handleProfileTransition(tapGesture: tapGesture)
      //  print("Tapped image")
    }



    override init(frame: CGRect){
        super.init(frame: frame)
        addSubview(textView)
        addSubview(profileImageView)
        addSubview(flagButton)
        textView.anchor(top: topAnchor, left: profileImageView.rightAnchor, bottom: bottomAnchor, right: rightAnchor, paddingTop: 4, paddingLeft: 4, paddingBottom: 4, paddingRight: 4, width: 0, height: 0)
        profileImageView.anchor(top: topAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: nil, paddingTop: 8, paddingLeft: 8, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 40, height: 40)
        profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 40/2
        flagButton.anchor(top: topAnchor, left: nil, bottom: nil, right: rightAnchor, paddingTop: 4, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 4, width: 40, height: 40)
        flagButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(CommentCell.onOptionsTapped), for: .touchUpInside)

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }




}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign textView's right anchor to the button's left one so they got aligned on sides. This would be the correct layout setup for the textView:

```
textView.anchor(top: topAnchor, left: profileImageView.rightAnchor, bottom: bottomAnchor, right: flagButton.leftAnchor, paddingTop: 4, paddingLeft: 4, paddingBottom: 4, paddingRight: 4, width: 0, height: 0)
```

Comment: can i ask one more question?

Comment: Sure, what’s your question?

Comment: though that has worked text seems to now look like this (see edits) is there any way to make it present itself better in the event that there is more text

Comment: You can try textView.textContainer.lineBreakMode = .byCharWrapping (more info here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nstextcontainer/1444519-linebreakmode )